# How to Map a Django model field to some user defined value

Tags: python, angularjs, django, django-models

Hi My project works on Django and some AngularJS. I want map my Django model field values into some custom string values. The following is my Model,

```
class History(models.Model):
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (1, 'CREATE'),
        (0, 'EDIT'),
        (2, 'DELETE'),
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='+')
    mw = models.ForeignKey('CP', related_name="history")
    field_name = models.CharField(max_length=192, null=False)
    old_value = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    new_value = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    type = models.IntegerField(default=0, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

the type 1, 2 and 0 I need to display in my website. So i just passed the value as `<td>{{t.type}}</td>` But it giving me the values as 1, 2 and 0. How can I display it as create, update or delete string values? Any idea guys? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take note that if you mixed django template language and some other template language like (angularjs) there will be a different outcome.

So i assume you are using angular? if thats the case 
try this

```
 <!-- if using angular js -->

{% verbatim %}
  {{ data.angular_t }}  {{ angularvariablescope }}
{% endverbatim %}

<!-- all django varibale  -->

{{t.type}} to  {{ t.get_type_display }}. {# django variable #}
```

or on your model.py

```
@property
def angular_t(self)
    return self.get_type_display()
```

retrieve that property on your resource (tastypie)

```
class Resource(ModelResource):
    angular_t = fields.CharField(attributes='angular_t', null=True)
```

Comment: Wow! Awesome. Thats what I was looking for. Thanks Jonard23 :)

Answer (score 6):

In your template change `{{t.type}}` to  `{{ t.get_type_display }}`.

You can read about this in docs: [get_FOO_display docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display)

Comment: Sorry am very new to Django, what is get_type_display? Is it a user defined definition? How to do that  Dima?

Comment: So I dont need to do anything on models? Where do I call this FOO method? In views?

Comment: Yes Kudosh, but my question is where do i need to include this definition? Is it inside the models or Views? What will be the impact for my existing data?

Comment: `def type(self):
        return self.get_type_display()` like this in models will do? But its not working..

Comment: In your example better to call it in template. Simply pass to your template variable of History class. And in template write {{ some_variable_name.get_(name of field, in your case type)_display}} And django will automatically call get_FOO_display function when render template. It mean that you must change only one string in template {{t.type}} to {{ t.get_type_display }}, and nothing in views or models

Comment: `<td>{{t.get_type_display}}</td>` Just like that only? But it displayed nothing in my template Dima

Comment: <td>{{t.type}}</td> it's display numbers?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94306/discussion-between-dima-kudosh-and-vellattukudy).

Comment: Sorry Dima, access denied for private chat.

Comment: it's very strange, it must work, can you show your views.py and full template

Comment: Am using Django 1.6? Does it affect?

Comment: Sorry Dima, I was using angularJS looping. Thats y it didnt work